# Why is my nl2br() function displaying \r instead of a break(<br />)? PHP

Tags: php

When I use the function nl2br($text) it doesn't display the breaks I want it to but instead shows the \r of where the breaks are to be. I am display a confirmation page for a user that shows the detail they entered in the form.

```
(the confirmation code in php)
// Confirm success with the user
    echo '<p>You have successfully posted a ad.'; 
    echo 'Here is your posting: <br /><br />';
    echo 'Title: ' .$title. '<br />' ;
    echo 'Price $: ' .$price.'<br />' ;
    echo 'Location: ' .$city. ' ' .$state. '<br />' ;
    echo '<b>Detail: </b>' .nl2br($detail). '<br />';

(The form users fill out)
<div class="fieldwrapper">
<label for="detail" class="styled">Detail:</label>
<div class="thefield">
    <textarea id="detail" name="detail"><?php if (!empty($detail)) echo $detail; ?></textarea>
```

```
(The output)
This is a test\r\n\r\ntesting is good\r\n\r\nWhy doesn\'t it work?
```

Comment: When I did a test run of echo '<b>Detail: </b>' .nl2br($detail). '<br />' by itself, it seemed to work and would show the spaces and not \r\n. Only here it doesn't seem to work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$input = 'this \r\nis what\r\ni want\r\n\r\n\r\nd'; 
echo nl2br(str_replace('\r', '', $input);
```

Remove \r first and that should help.

Comment: thank you very much! Got it to work. Hate those \r\n things :/

Comment: Haha no problem, just make sure no one types in \r since you are filtering it out. Cheers mate.

Comment: @ggfan you kidding. are you really do that stupid str_replace('\r', '', $input)?

Answer (score 0):

Because \r is not a [newline character in the *nix sense](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline#Representations) (aka "[line feed](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/000a/index.htm)" character) - it's a "[carriage return](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/000d/index.htm)" character.

There's [historical reasons why both exist](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline#History), but these days it's just really an annoyance that us programmers have to deal with.

As JonnyLitt answered - you'll have to remove the \r characters yourself prior to using `nl2br()`.

Answer (score 0):

`\r` were **already** in your text. **not a carriage return sumbols** but literally 2-symbol sequence - a backslash fllowed by `r` letter.
You have to find a place in your code that converts newlines to `\r` sequences. addslashes after mysql_real_escape_string() may do the thing

Update:
After your comment I got it.
You 're using single quotes to delimit your string.
REad PHP syntax and don't worry. The real data would be fine.